# WordrPess plugin in MVC way

Tags: wordpress, model-view-controller, plugins

does anyone have the MVC WordPress boilerplate for the WordPress plugin development?

Please share with me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are a few on GitHub [such as this one](https://github.com/rrodrigonuez/MVC-WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate)